# Is it possible to calculate how many maps in the document in firestore? If yes, Is it possible to user ListView.builder?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My document has 7 maps. I have to create 7 ListTiles using 7 maps. Is it need to create one by one listView? Or Is there any way to create 1 listTile and assign 7 maps values?

```
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: db.getRequirement(uid),
            builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<RequirementModel> snapshot) {
               return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    pendingWidget(snapshot.data.drivingLicense.status),
                    pendingWidget(snapshot.data.nic.status),
                    pendingWidget(snapshot.data.vehiclePhotos.status),
                    pendingWidget(snapshot.data.vehicleLicense.status),
                  ],
                );
          ),
```

**custom Widget**

```
 Widget pendingWidget(String status) {
    return ListTile(
        dense: true,
        title: CustomText(
          text:Strings.drivingLicense
        ),
        subtitle: CustomText(
          text: status
        )
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done in ListView.builder. In fact its better for large amount of  list view items, as it only builds items that are visible on the screen. Meanwhile, ListView builds everything at once regardless whether they are visible or not.

You could refer to the following link by google to learn how to work on this;

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists